# PyGithub - Can't set attribute error while trying to change default branch

Tags: python, pygithub

I've written this code to change the default branch from "master" to "release".

```
from github import Github
g = Github("github token", verify=False, base_url="url to repo")

repo = g.get_repo("repo name")
repo.default_branch = 'release'
```

I am getting the following error.

```
   repo.default_branch = 'release'
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I am the admin of that repository and I created the branch. I don't think this is an access issue. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `default_branch` attribute is a read-only attribute; if you want to *change* the default branch you need to use the [`edit`](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html#github.Repository.Repository.edit) method:

```
repo.edit(default_branch='release')
```

Comment: Same for `delete_branch_on_merge` and other repo's properties.